# Add dependency in build.gradle in corda 5

Tags: corda

I need to add dependencies in build.gradle in corda 5.
As we use to add plugin and associated dependency in corda 4, what is the procedure to do this in corda 5?
I want to add kotlin plugin so what is the dependency associated with it, as I am getting error
Plugin [id: 'kotlin'] was not found in any of the following sources.